# Clearing javascript cache in ie10 not working, can no longer debug javascript changes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, browser-cache

Now that I have upgraded to IE10, it's very difficult to get my javascript changed files to get recognized.

In IE9, you could simply use the 'clear the cache' button in the develepor panel and could see your javascript changes.

This no longer works (apparently) -- is there some other way to get IE10 to dump your cache?  This is brutal!

On Windows 7, using VS2010 and just upgraded to IE10.

Comment: Under Tools Menu, you will find F12 Developer tools. If you open this you will find a Cache tab in the tools window. You will find Clear Cache if you click on it (CTRL + R). Is this what you are looking for.

Comment: Sort of...that is the same as the clear cache button in the developer panel and what I am saying is that it is not working (for my scripts anyway)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I found out the answer... it appears that IE10 either added (or added this as a default) a setting 'PRESERVE FAVORITES WEBSITE DATA' ... this was checked (by default) and although I havent thoroughly tested it, I think this is why my js files were not being purged.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's incredibly easy to get bugs due to bad caching. Developing with caching turned on (and manually purging the cache) is mission-impossible.

If you're using a server-side scripting language to generate your page you can use fingerprinting.

You can add a querystring to the URL that is always different, this makes it so browsers will never cache the scripts. Very useful for development, terrible for live :P

Eg: `script.js?fingerprint=123456` where `123456` is a different number each page load.

A more involved solution would look at actual changes in the source code.

Comment: Ya, you are right and I have done that before but after awhile those get in a few different places and then you forget to remove them... I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Depending on your framework you can collect all script includes and include them all through some kind of include manager. The include manager can then add the fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

In my web-based *mySQL* application, IE-10  (with default settings) often refuses to show the **present** state of the mySQL database. It usually shows the state of an earlier visit (showing records that were deleted, or not showing records that were added).

This is a consequence of a changeable IE-10 setting. (Unfortunately I have only access to a Dutch-speaking IE-10, MS refuses me to download an English speaking browser). In rough translation: go to Internet options/General. You see "Browsing History" with a button "Settings". Hit it and you will see radio buttons determining the search for fresh pages. The default is "automatic", change it to "search for fresh page on every visit". This fixed my problem

Unfortunately however, I don't know how to set this from within my app, so I have to inform my users about it. This is awkward.